# Applying Substring in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, split, substring

```
  List<DocumentDTO> lstDocs = objService
    .SelectDocumentInfo()
    .Where(l => int.Parse(l.FileName.Substring(0, l.FileName.IndexOf('\'))) = docID)
    .ToList();
```

My docID is an `int` value

```
279\Chrysanthemum.jpg
```

The 279 is my docID i want to get only those records which have a 279 in front of The FileName  as specified or if the docID changes to something else then only get those records through LINQ.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might be a workable approach:

```
List<DocumentDTO> lstDocs = objService.SelectDocumentInfo()
    .Where(l => l.FileName.StartsWith(string.Concat(docID, @"\"))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

You can also do like this

```
List<DocumentDTO> lstDocs = objService
    .SelectDocumentInfo()
    .Where(l => Convert.ToInt32( (l.FileName.Split('\\'))[0] )  == docID)
    .ToList();
```

by applying split function on string

---

one change in you code

```
 List<DocumentDTO> lstDocs = objService
.SelectDocumentInfo()
.Where(l => int.Parse(l.FileName.Substring(0, l.FileName.IndexOf('\'))) == docID)
.ToList();
```

you need to put "==" instead of "=" check correct code above

---

Note : this works if you have string like 279\Chrysanthemum.jpg only if its like this 279\Chrysanthemum1.jpg than this fails

just fetch number from string like this and try out

```
  stringThatHaveCharacters = stringThatHaveCharacters.Trim();
    Match m = Regex.Match(stringThatHaveCharacters, "\\d+");
    int number = Convert.ToInt32(m.Value);
```

So try like this

```
  List<DocumentDTO> lstDocs = objService
    .SelectDocumentInfo()
    .Where(l => Convert.ToInt32( (Regex.Match(l.FileName, "\\d+")).Value)  == docID)
    .ToList();
```